# Problems with reinstalling El Capitan using DVD

Tags: macos, imac

Let me preface that I am a total apple noob. I only used iMacs at work, and that was only for about 20 mins a day.

My workplace upgraded their computers, and I found out my laptop decided to die. Due to lockdown I can't really go and get it fixed (ie. Can't do my training they're paying for,) so they allowed me to take the old iMac. Of course they've erased everything but forgot to reinstall macOS.

Following the steps I found online I tried to reinstall but not knowing the apple ID, I can't do it (and seems like El Capitan needs it), and can't find anyone that's not furloughed and would have the knowledge of it. I did manage to get a working bootable DVD with El Capitan. I can see the disk recognised when in os utilities, but when restarting and pressing whichever combination of keys (one website said to just press C, another one to press Option) I just get the apple logo on a white background, the normal loading screen. It does load up to the end and then just gets stuck there forever.

I don't really know where to go from here.

I am probably just missing a very obvious step somewhere, and I'm more than happy to be proven on my stupidity and inability to follow simple instructions. I've never been great with computers but frankly, this is way beyond my brain power.

Comment: Which model iMac is it?  If you're not sure, try looking up the S/N number (located on the back of the machine) at https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/.

Comment: Okay so assuming I've written it down correctly, the serial number is VM9367EY0TJ

Comment: You were supposed to use the link that @Allan posted to look up the model information yourself. iMac 24-Inch "Core 2 Duo" 2.66 (Early 2009)

Comment: Based on that, it's a Early 2009 iMac.  Do you have access to another Mac so you can make the USB installer?  Is it possible that the folks from your work can create the installer for you?  DVD installers are a bodge that gives lots of trouble.

Comment: I don't have access to another Mac but I'm sure I could ask someone to create an installer for me and send it my way, looking online it doesn't seem like too much of a difficult task. Worst comes to worse, looking online there's tons (possibly equally as dodgy) of USB installers I could purchase that are not exactly expensive, so if plan a fails, I might just do that. Thanks though!

Comment: Just use OS X Utilities to reinstall OS X El Capitan.